# How Wild Card (?) and Type Parameter(T) differ while using as method parameter

Tags: java, generics

```
 public class Util {

   public static <T> void printList(List<T> list){
    for (Object obj : list){
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
 }

 public static void printListWithWildCard(List<?> list){
    for (Object obj : list){
        System.out.println(obj);
     }
   }
 }



 public class Main {

   public static void main(String arg[]){

    Util.printList(Arrays.asList("test",2,3));
    Util.printListWithWildCard(Arrays.asList("test",2,3));
    }
  }
```

In the methods **printList()** and **printListWithWildCard()** what is the difference when accepting parameters as `List<T> list` and  when accepting parameters as`List<?> list`??

Comment: In the first version, the generic type has a name, `T`, so you can refer to it inside the method (or in the return type).

Answer (score 0):

in both methods you are actually just printing the content of the list, so that can trick your mind  but the real issue is that in this method,

```
 printListWithWildCard(List<?> list)
```

java has no idea what the list is holding an can block you to do some operations with it...

let me explain myself with this example:

```
public static <T> void printList(List<T> list) {
    list.add(list.get(0));

}

public static void printListWithWildCard(List<?> list) {
    list.add(list.get(0));

}
```

now try to compile that code and you will see that the error arise:

> The method add(capture#1-of ?) in the type List is not
>   applicable for the arguments (capture#2-of ?)

Answer (score 0):

While using `List<T>` then we are specifing this list as list of specific object.

Like, if we want to create list of Person object. Then we can mention it as `List<Person>`

But if Employee is subclass of Person class and if we want to have list of Person or list of subclass of Person then we can use wildcard character.

Like, `List<? extends Person>` then we can pass list as `List<Person>` or `List<Employee>`.

If you define list as `List<T>` and |List` then currently both are same no difference. But actual use of wildcard character is to define subclass or parent class of any object.